# centering root div through percentage width in all kind of resolutions

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to center the root div through percentage based width not pixel based

```
#container
{
  width:80%;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

it will center the container respective to page and working fine in 1366 *706 reoslution. **but not working in 1280*1024**

i need to center the div to work in both kind of resolutions. how can i resolve this issue when  using percentage width concept.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: what do you mean by 'but not working in 1280*1024' ? the percentage is not applied ?

Comment: @phron its applied not centered in page

Comment: @CodingAnt how margin-left: 50% helpful ? not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xy6dF/)**

**The HTML Code:**

```
<div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
```

**The CSS Code:**

```
#container
{
  width:80%;
  margin:0px auto;
    background:green;
}

html{width:100%; min-width:100%;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: whether it will works in all kind of reolutsions ? i mentioned in my question need to center the dive in two resolutions.

Comment: Yes. It does. But this purely depend on what things you want to put inside your div - @SivaRajini

Comment: Sorry i tried your solution but still same problem working in one resolution and not working in other resolution

Comment: Thats strange. Paste your full div code here. - @SivaRajini

Comment: The fiddle is working. No issues on it. - @SivaRajini I assume that you have a `min-width` value in your website on your CSS Style that is preventing it to behave responsively.

Answer (score 0):

add padding-left and padding-right. also give width=100%

Comment: i need to work in all resolutions could you provide me sample demo.

Comment: can you add some sample html ? what exactly are you trying to execute

Comment: i need root div center to page in two resolutions. how do you center the div in percentage width to work in all resolutions